# Show camera with pause(take picture) on tap

Tags: ios, camera

I am trying to create an app for my job as a mechanic.

1). i need to be able to have front cam come up but with white bars around the side(to provide light

2). on tap it pauses and displays the picture without saveing it to camera library(if i kept those id be out of space in no time.

3). i would like to be able to have the same thing for the back camera minus the white bars.

as of now im very now toxcode and will need a lot of help. but haveing this app will make some jobs 100X easier.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/. Try this on for size.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for asking specific programming questions. So far you have listed a set of requirements and have not asked a question. Please update your question with something specific.